# Lighted bookcase with capacitive touch hinge

Tags: electrical, lighting

A while ago I saw a lighted bookcase at a furniture store whereby you could turn its lights on and off (actually dim them by a couple of levels), just by touching one of the hinges on one of the cupboard doors.

Does anyone know if there are pre-packaged components for such a thing, or what would be involved in setting up my own for a bookcase I want to build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

They have them for sale on E-Bay for less than $20, they are designed to work with incandescent 3-way bulbs but I think they make them for LEDs now too. [Try E-Bay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Zing-Ear-TP-01-ZH-Touch-Light-Table-Lamp-Dimmer-Switch-Control-Module-Sensor-/141371439504)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are prepackaged touch switch modules whose input wire can be attached to any convenient piece of metal.